# Google Videointelligence API - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning, Requests per minute

Tags: node.js, video-intelligence-api

I'm using Google Videointelligence API and according the documentation of the Quota & Limits, I can process ~3 videos parallel (and it works fine), but when I process more then 3 videos in parallel, exception was thrown.

**The issue is that I can't catch this exception!**

**The exception: 
  (node:31660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' of service 'videointelligence.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:852521347926'.**

I'm writing in node.js.

the code is just like the example:

```
const [operation] = await client.annotateVideo(request);
logger.debug('Waiting for enrichment operation to complete...');
try{
        const [operationResult] = await operation.promise(); //Exception was thrown on this line
}catch(err){
        console.log("exception was caught");//failed to catch the exception
}
```

Comment: That looks like an appropriate error for when you go over quota. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I have the same issue. And like OP said, I can't catch that exception. I tried attaching an event listener on the `operation` object but it didn't work.